# Why does replacing the dollar sign ($) with parentheses in this expression leads to an error?

Tags: haskell

I have these two expressions:

1. `foldr (-) 0 . map (uncurry (*)) $ coords 5 7`
2. `foldr (-) 0 . map (uncurry (*)) (coords 5 7)`

The (1) works print out the result, but (2) have error says:

```
<interactive>:50:15:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> t0 c’
                with actual type ‘[Integer]’
    Relevant bindings include
      it :: a -> c (bound at <interactive>:50:1)
    Possible cause: ‘map’ is applied to too many arguments
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely
      ‘map (uncurry (*)) (coords 5 7)’
    In the expression: foldr (-) 0 . map (uncurry (*)) (coords 5 7)
```

Can any one tell me what's the difference between these two? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an easier example:

```
Prelude> id . id $ "Example"
"Example"
Prelude> id . id ("Example")
<interactive>:2:10:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> c’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    Relevant bindings include it :: a -> c (bound at <interactive>:2:1)
    In the first argument of ‘id’, namely ‘("Example")’
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘id ("Example")’
    In the expression: id . id ("Example")
```

The problem is that function application binds stronger than `(.)`. The fixity level of `($)` fixes this:

```
id . id $ "Example" = (id . id) $ "Example"
                    = (id . id) "Example"
```

However, with `(...)`, the function application wins and you end up using `(.)` with a non-function as second argument:

```
id . id ("Example") = id . id "Example"
                    = id . (id "Example") -- apply id
                    = id . ("Example")
                    = type error, since "Example" isn't a function
```

Comment: I see now, thanks, I am wondering why (uncurry (*)) ) as a argument with a () didn't cause the problem but the last argument (coords 5 7) did? and btw, what if there are multiple $ in the expression? How would the interpreter interpret the expression?

Answer (score 3):

```
foldr (-) 0 . map (uncurry (*)) $ coords 5 7
-- is equivalent to
( foldr (-) 0 . map (uncurry (*)) )  (coords 5 7)
-- and to
foldr (-) 0 ( map (uncurry (*)) (coords 5 7) )


foldr (-) 0 . map (uncurry (*)) (coords 5 7)
-- is equivalent to
foldr (-) 0 . ( map (uncurry (*)) (coords 5 7) )
-- and to
\x -> foldr (-) 0 ( map (uncurry (*)) (coords 5 7) x)
```

In the latter, the result of `map (uncurry (*)) (coords 5 7)` is passed to `.` as its second argument, but it's a list, not a function, so a type error arises.

Note that is is also OK:

```
foldr (-) 0 $ map (uncurry (*)) (coords 5 7)
```

Answer (score 2):

`$` is simply a no-op in infix form. Because it's an infix operator with low fixity:

```
GHCi> :i $
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
infixr 0 $
```

any expression in which it occurs is parsed *as if* it had parenthesis. In your example,

```
foldr (-) 0 . map (uncurry (*)) $ coords 5 7
```

is parsed as

```
  (   (foldr (-) 0)
    . (map (uncurry (*))) )
$ (coords 5 7)
```

because `$` has lower fixity than `.`. This works in exactly the same way as if you write `1 + 2 * 3`: this is parsed as `(1) + (2*3)`, because `*` has higher fixity than `+`.

When the `$` operator is then *evaluated*, all it does is apply the function on the LHS – in you case, this is `foldr (-) 0 . map (uncurry (*))` – to the RHS expression `coords 5 7`. Applying a function to its argument is of course also exactly what happens if you just wrote `function (argument)`, however you need to specify the correct function! To write you example without `$`, you must group it as

```
( foldr (-) 0 . map (uncurry (*)) ) (coords 5 7)
```

whereas your attempt is parsed differently: function application binds more tightly than any infix, even `.`, so your attempt is equivalent to

```
foldr (-) 0 . ( map (uncurry (*)) (coords 5 7) )
```

which doesn't make sense.